# Pivot on two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have two columns - one with column ID, and one with data belonging to this column.

Raw data:

```
+---------+--------+
| ColName | Values |
+---------+--------+
| Column1 |     13 |
| Column1 |     86 |
| Column1 |     16 |
| Column1 |     18 |
| Column1 |      2 |
| Column1 |     11 |
| Column1 |     28 |
| Column1 |      3 |
| Column1 |     13 |
| Column1 |     13 |
| Column1 |     90 |
| Column2 |     35 |
| Column2 |     69 |
| Column2 |     26 |
| Column2 |     71 |
| Column2 |     32 |
| Column2 |     69 |
| Column2 |     87 |
| Column2 |     58 |
| ColumnN |     13 |
| ColumnN |     54 |
| ColumnN |     79 |
| ColumnN |     86 |
| ColumnN |     47 |
| ColumnN |     37 |
| ColumnN |     65 |
| ColumnN |     49 |
| ColumnN |     89 |
| ColumnN |     27 |
+---------+--------+
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | ColumnN |
+---------+---------+---------+
|      13 | 35      | 13      |
|      86 | 69      | 54      |
|      16 | 26      | 79      |
|      18 | 71      | 86      |
|       2 | 32      | 47      |
|      11 | 69      | 37      |
|      28 | 87      | 65      |
|       3 | 58      | 49      |
|      13 | NULL    | 89      |
|      13 | NULL    | 27      |
|      90 | NULL    | NULL    |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

I need this to be dynamic, as number Columns in the ID field are not known.
Also, data in the Values field is completely arbitrary. It can be anything and any count of rows.

I did some testing with the `crosstab` function, but it seems to be applicable only when we have a third column in the raw data.

Any guidance?

Comment: It is not clear from your example just what mapping you want from the input to output tables. How are you assembling an output row from input rows? Do you get a row for every `value` value? Please edit your question to finish the following sentence: row (v1,...) with columns (c1,...) is in the output if and only if .... PS Why are you doing this? What do you to on to do with this? (Apparently the input & output are both heavily redundant.)

Comment: Did you get satisfaction re dum/dee?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple below statement

```
select a.cvalue col1  , b.cvalue col2
from
(select cvalue from stack_overflow where column_id = 'column1') a
join
(select cvalue from stack_overflow where column_id = 'column2') b
on a.cvalue = b.cvalue
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is a bit static. I need the number of columns in the result to not be predefined.